# PHP Session destroy twice?

Tags: php, forms, session

Upon entering the "secure" page, I have an if statement asking if the user is logged in, as shown below.

This statement baffles me as the outcome of both statements are the same, but it is the only way for me to end session when refreshing page. So if I change the statement to `if (!session == user) {session_destroy} else { continue with session}`, refreshing the page will have the session going.

*edit* **The `if/else` statement in `session.php` is the one I do not understand. How can I have an `if/else` statement with two equal outcomes and yet receive two different outcomes in practice. As I enter my login credentials, I enter the `session.php`. If I refresh, I end up back at `index.php`. However, my statement claims that if I have session variables, then destroy session. If I do not have session variables, destroy session. What am I overlooking?** *edit*

Secure page `session.php` below.

```
<?php
// To connection
require("includes/functions.php");


// Is the user logged in?
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { 

    //If user not set, destroy session.
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    exit(); 
} else {
    //Here is the funky part, why have if condition with two predicted equal statements, but have two different outcomes. 
    // If set, destroy session.
    session_destroy();
} //Then the anything below should be secure. 
?>
```

My `functions.php` (the included one) file is actually a connect to db with a `session_start()`. The `login_process.php` page looks as follows.

> ```
> <?php
>
> // Connection
> require_once("functions.php"); 
>
> //Once form has been clicked, the submitted name reappears, but first empty.
> $submitted_username = ''; 
>
> // IS form submitted?
> if(!empty($_POST['login'])) 
> { 
>     // Find username
>     $query = " 
>         SELECT 
>             id, 
>             username, 
>             password, 
>             salt, 
>             email 
>         FROM users 
>         WHERE 
>             username = :username 
>     "; 
>
>     // The parameter values 
>     $query_params = array( 
>         ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
>     ); 
>
>     try 
>     { 
>         // Execute the query against the database 
>         $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
>         $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
>     } 
>     catch(PDOException $ex) 
>     { 
>         die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
>     } 
>
>     // Login bad first 
>     $login_ok = false; 
>
>     // Find user
>     $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
>     if($row) 
>     { 
>         // Check password
>         $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
>         for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
>         { 
>             $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
>         } 
>
>         if($check_password === $row['password']) 
>         { 
>             // If match, login good. 
>             $login_ok = true; 
>         } 
>     } 
>
>     // If allgood session start.
>     if($login_ok) 
>     { 
>         unset($row['salt']); 
>         unset($row['password']); 
>
>         //Issue here?
>         $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
>
>         // Redirect user to secret page. 
>         header("Location: session.php"); 
>         exit; 
>     } 
>     else 
>     { 
>         // Tell the user they failed 
>         $login_failed = "<p class='clear floatleft'>Login Failed.</p>"; 
>
>         $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
>     } 
> }  ?>
> ```

The `require_once` in `login_process.php` is due to `login_form.php` being added as an include on every page. Thus always creating a `session_start();`. See `login_form` below.

```
<?php include('login_process.php'); ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<!--                Sign in form       -->
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="">

    <input class="inline" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    <input class="inline" type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up">
</form>
<?php if(isset($login_failed)) {
         echo $login_failed;
     }
?>
```

The form is picked up from a tutorial, please understand that I am not as of yet capable of producing such a login form rendering. I like to think that I understand the blocks of code by the comments I have created.

But I digest, I do not understand how the `if/else` statement in `session.php` can have two equal values and render differently. So any help on this particular subject would be greatly appreciated.

This question may be a duplicate, I have read so many questions regarding sessions that I feel blind to finding any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see your page containing `session_start()` anywhere. You have to put that into EVERY page where you use sessions.
You should also sanitaze your `$_POST` values against HTML characters.

Comment: `session_start()` is included in the `functions.php` which is included in every page. Yes, the sanitation I shall also think of.

Comment: I reread your question, and I cannot find what thing you are exactly asking about. Please edit your question, to make people easier understand your problem.

Comment: I have now edited the question, thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Digress*

Your code is doing exactly what it is written to do. Just as you think it is.

When a user inputs their credentials and is successful in *login_process.php* at -

```
if($login_ok) 
    { 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 

        //Issue here?
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;

        // Redirect user to secret page. 
        header("Location: session.php"); 
        exit; 
    } 
    else 
    {
```

The user is redirected to session.php to have their session destroyed. Why? Because the code says that if the user has nothing in *$_SESSION['user']*

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { 

    //If user not set, destroy session.
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    exit();
```

then destroy the session.

OTHERWISE destroy session.

So no matter what the user session is destroyed. Successful or not.

The reason you don't get redirected until a refresh is because after you log in --successfully-- your session is destroyed. Then on refresh(of the same page) you satisfy the check for

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { 

    //If user not set, destroy session.
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    exit();
```

because $_SESSION['user'] no longer exists. Thus it redirects you to the homepage.

TL;DR *session_destroy()* cleared *$_SESSION['user']* and a refresh on the same page causes user to clear first check of *if* statement.

Comment: Yeah, layman terms are what's needed. This is how I understand (correct me if I am wrong) "if session['user'] not set, destroy and redirect", and "if session["user"] set just destroy but stay on page until refreshed". Thanks Quentin, I removed the else statement, and will try to set a session time limit instead, and then just have a logout page.